# Finding the center of a logistic curve

Tags: logistic-curve, sigmoid-curve

Given a sigmoidal/logistic curve p

[image]

what's the general procedure to finding at what value of x is the curve centered?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: I suppose its center would be where $p=1/2$ (what else could it possibly be?).  Solve that for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) page and note that 
$$ -(5 - 6 x) = -(-6)(x - 5/6).$$